# Как вывести в лог информацию о системе

Tags: логирование

Как вывести в лог информацию о системе

```
import platform
import logging


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filename="app_test1.log", filemode="w")

logging.info('Version           : ', platform.python_version())
```

Получаю ошибку

Comment: какую ошибку выдаёт?

Answer (score 0):

Получилось

```
import platform
import logging


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,filename="app_test2.log", filemode="w")
logging.info("Information about System")
logging.info((f'Version           : ', {platform.python_version()} ))
logging.info((f'Version tuple     : ', {platform.python_version_tuple()}))
logging.info((f'Compiler          : ', {platform.python_compiler()}))
```